# jQuery - help needed implementing fakepath fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im using the following code to implement some JS for my file input field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[id=lefile]').change(function() {
    $('#photoCover').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

This all works fine, but when a file is chosen, it displays the c:\fakepath rubbish

I have found a bit of code that gets rid of it, which is as follows, but im finding it hard to work out how to implement it.

```
var s = $(self).val().replace(/(c:\\)*fakepath/i, '');
filename.val(s);
```

Can someone help me to change my code to implement the replace.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, just append `.val().replace(/(c:\\)*fakepath/i, '');` onto the end of your .val():

```
$('input[id=lefile]').change(function() {
    $('#photoCover').val($(this).val().replace(/(c:\\)*fakepath/i, ''));
});
```